# Animating divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate a series of divs with the same dimentions and I'm using Jquery to cancel css top marging on load as to simulate the divs moving to top
I currently have the fallowing jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#some_div').animate({'margin-top': '0px'}, 1000);
});
    </script>
```

This only seems to work with the top div. Is there a way to create some sort of loop so my jquery simulates this effect on all divs with that same name.

Comment: $('#some_div') means just the div with id='some_div' you can use $('div') to get all divs or select by class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector points to an item by ID. by definition an ID should only ever refer to one element. Change it to a class selector to animate many items and give them all the same class.

Comment: The only problem is that I need to apply different styles to that id in different cases and I'm using classes for this ex. <div id="some-div"></div><div id="some-div" class="greybg"></div><div id="some-div"></div>Any suggestions?

Comment: you can add more than one class declaration at a time to an element. Try class="animate-me greybg"

Comment: Feel free to mark my response as the answer if you found it helpful. good luck!